# How can we make an activity receive two parcelable objects from two different activities

Tags: android, android-intent

this code doesn't give errors but while running this in emulator the "fromactivity2" message isn't displayed.

```
    Bundle messagereceiver = getIntent().getExtras();

    String fromactivity1 = messagereciever.getString("message1");

    displaytext.setText(fromactivity1);

    //Second Activity

    Bundle messagereceiver2 = getIntent().getExtras();

    String fromactivity2 = messagereceiver2.getString("message2");

    displaytext2.setText(fromactivity2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send it via Intent using (putExtra)

intent.putExtra("yourId", objectBundle);

Comment: Well i did use intent.putExtra("stringid",string). i have 2 different activities from which i am sending 2 different objects(using .putExtra) and receiving them from two different Bundles.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding I thought that the error in the way you are sending data. You mean that the data not shown? Please past a screen shot